# Blazor Server: <InputSelect and @oninput event is giving bizarre behavior

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I have a series of 3 InputSelects, with the 2nd one cascading from the first via SQL queries. I have additional logic that runs when the first dropdown is selected via the oninput event. (Im aware that onchange and bind-Value cant be declared on the same element).

Upon selecting the first, my value will populate but then disappears from the text area after a split-second, although the data is actually present in the model, and the rest of the logic works correctly, by populating the second box with related records:

**Before Selection:**
[image]

**After Selection:**
[image]

**Related Code:**

```
<EditForm Model="@plansold" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmit">
            <FluentValidator />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @if (categories == null)
                            {<p><em>Loading ...</em></p>} //Null check
                            else
                            {                                   
                                <InputSelect TValue="string" class="form-control" @bind-Value="plansold.PlanCategoryDesc" @oninput="CategoryChange">
                                    <option value="Select..." selected disabled="disabled">(Select Plan Category)</option>
                                    @foreach (var c in categories)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@c.id"> @c.Description</option>
                                    }
                                </InputSelect>
                                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => plansold.PlanCategoryDesc)" class="text-danger" />

                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**@code section**

```
 private async Task CategoryChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Value.ToString()) == false)
            {
                plansold.PlanCategory = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString());
                catid = plansold.PlanCategory; // int; model property
                plans = await plansService.GetPlanOptions(catid); //comes from SQL
                plandesc = await plansService.GetPlanDescByID(catid);  //comes from SQL
                plansold.PlanCategoryDesc = plandesc.Description; //string; model property
                
            }
            else
            {
                plansold.PlanCategory = 0;
            }
        }
```

Originally, these were plain  elements, and with @onchange, it worked fine, but to get validation messages to disappear the way my textboxes do, I switched to  and have spent all day in a rabbit hole trying to get the behavior set right. I have also tried bind-Value:event="CategoryChange" to no avail.

This is Blazor Server 5.0. Does any know how to persist the display in the dropdown elements after oninput events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two thumbs up for Syncfusion controls:

```
          <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @if (categories == null)
                    {<p><em>Loading ...</em></p>} //Null check
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="padding-top">
                            <SfDropDownList TItem="ITQA_CategoryModel" TValue="string" Placeholder="(Select Plan Category)" PopupHeight="auto" DataSource="@categories">
                                <DropDownListEvents TItem="ITQA_CategoryModel" TValue="string" ValueChange="@CategoryChange"></DropDownListEvents>
                                <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Description" Value="id"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
                            </SfDropDownList>
                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => plansold.PlanCategoryDesc)" class="text-danger" />
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="padding-top">
                        <SfDropDownList Enabled="@PlansDetailEnabled" TItem="ITQA_PlansModel" TValue="string" Placeholder="(Select Plan Length)" PopupHeight="auto" DataSource="@plans">
                            <DropDownListEvents TItem="ITQA_PlansModel" TValue="string" ValueChange="@PlanChange"></DropDownListEvents>
                            <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="PlanLength" Value="id"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
                        </SfDropDownList>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => plansold.PlanLength)" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

 private async Task CategoryChange(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<string, ITQA_CategoryModel> args)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Value.ToString()) == false)
    {
        catid = Convert.ToInt32(args.Value);
        plans = await plansService.GetPlanOptions(catid);
        plansold.PlanCategory = Convert.ToInt32(args.Value);
        plansold.PlanCategoryDesc = args.ItemData.Description;
        PlansDetailEnabled = true;

    }
}

private void PlanChange(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<string, ITQA_PlansModel> args)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Value.ToString()) == false)
    {
        plansold.PlanLength = args.ItemData.PlanLength;
        plansold.PlanCost = args.ItemData.PlanCost;
    }
}
```